# Removing particular string from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have text in a range of cells like

Manufacturer#||#Coaster#|#|Width (side to side)#||#20" W####Height (bottom to top)#||#35" H#|#|Depth (front to back)#||#20.5" D####Seat Depth#||#14.25"**#|#|Material & Finish####**Composition#||#Wood Veneers & Solids#|#|Composition#||#Metal#|#|Style Elements####Style#||#Contemporary#|#|Style#||#Casual

From this cell i need to remove strings between #|#|"needtoremove"#### only without affecting other strings. 
I have tried find and replace, finding #|#|*#### and replacing it with #|#|. However its not giving the exact result.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you post the specifics of what you've tried, you're more likely to have someone help you fix it, as opposed to having it written for you.

Comment: There are so many `#|#|` and `####` Which of the values are you looking for?

Comment: i Should remove all the strings between #|#| and #### but not between #|#| and #|#| and ####

Answer (score 1):

The other solution will remove anything between the first #|#| and ####, event the #||# etc.

In case you only need to remove the text between #|#| and #### only if there is no other ##|| inbetween, I think the simplest way is to use a regex.

You will need to activate the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library in Tools->References from the VBA editor.

Change range("D166") to wherever your cell is. The expression as it is right now ("#\|#\|[A-Za-z0-9& ]*####")matches any text that starts with #|#|, ends with #### and has any number of alphanumerical character, & or space. You can add other caracters between the brakets if needed.

```
Sub remove()
Dim reg As New RegExp
Dim pattern As String
Dim replace As String
Dim strInput As String
strInput = Range("D166").Value
replace = ""
pattern = "#\|#\|[A-Za-z0-9& ]*####"
With reg
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .pattern = pattern
End With


If reg.test(strInput) Then Range("D166").Value = reg.replace(strInput, replace)

End Sub
```

Comment: I got error on "Dim reg As New RegExp" should i do?

Comment: Did you add the reference to the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5?
Here is a step by step on doing so:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/5042442

You only need to do the step 1 steps.

Comment: Sry i know English only that link has some other language

Comment: This link is definitely english... [Here is the msdn entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx) on adding a reference. You can change the language at the bottom left if it's easier to you. Then you need to find Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 in the window that opens.

Comment: Hi Latch, thanks for helping :)

Finally my source has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

If that value is in cell A1

```
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

str = ws.Range("A1").Value
i = InStr(str, "#|#|")
i2 = InStr(str, "####")

str = Left(str, i) & Right(str, Len(str) - i2)

ws.Range("A1").Value = str
```

Comment: I added the line at the bottom to write the modified string in the variable back to the spreadsheet.  As is stated this is just modifying cell A1.  If you need a loop example i can provide it.

Comment: ws needs to be your worksheet.  I will add that for you.

Comment: Hi MathewD, thanks for helping :)

Finally my source has been updated.